# Paypal adaptive payments for digital goods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paypal

I am struggling to figure out how to get Digital goods to work with my adaptive payments. I am using the `Paypal ruby gem` can someone please show me a code sample for a payments with 2 receivers and for `Digital Goods`?

I already am approved for micro payments by paypal.

```
# Build request object
        @pay = @api.build_pay({
          :actionType => "PAY",
          :cancelUrl => "http://localhost:3000/account", #sandbox
          :currencyCode => "USD",
          #:feesPayer => "SENDER",
          :ipnNotificationUrl => "http://596w.localtunnel.com/pay/#{purchased.id}", #sandbox
          :memo => "Test payment",
          :receiverList => {
            :receiver => [{
              :amount => price.round(2),
              :email => "an email", #sandbox
              :paymentType => "DIGITALGOODS",
              :primary => true
              },
              unless account.user.email == "an email"
              {
                :amount => mycut.round(2),
                :email => "anemail", #sandbox
                :paymentType => "DIGITALGOODS" 
                }
              end
                ] },
          :returnUrl => "http://localhost:3000/pay/complete/" #sandbox 
          })
```

I get the error:

```
This feature (Digital Goods) is not supported.
```

Comment: Does it work for single receiver? Or with default :paymentType?
And do you get this error exactly on build_pay call?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know on the the Express Payment option of Paypal supports digital good. if you can replace your integration to use `activemerchant` and use the `PaypalDigitalGoodsGateway` you'd do yourself a favor.

Answer (score 0):

Log a ticket at https://www.paypal.com/mts and they'll enable it for you.
For what it's worth, the product you're trying to use is: Digital Goods for Express Checkout.
Express Checkout itself is available by default on all accounts, but that team can enable Digital Goods on your Sandbox account.

Answer (score 0):

This error may appear if you get the payKey successfully but redirect user to wrong url later.

Here is haml code for form for embedded payments, including Digital Goods.

```
= javascript_include_tag "//www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/apdg.js"

%form.text-center{:action => ::PAYPAL_ADAPTIVE_GATEWAY.embedded_flow_url, :target => "PPDGFrame"}
  %input#type{:name => "expType", :type => "hidden", :value => "light"}
  %input#paykey{:name => "payKey", :type => "hidden", :value => @payKey}
  %input#submitBtn{:type => "submit", :value => 'Pay with PayPal' }

:javascript
  var returnFromPayPal = function(){
  //do something on PayPal popup closing here
  };
  var dgFlowMini = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlowMini({ trigger: 'submitBtn', callbackFunction: returnFromPayPal});

  //works only for lightbox mode
  function MyEmbeddedFlow(embeddedFlow) {
      this.embeddedPPObj = embeddedFlow;
      this.paymentSuccess = function () {
           this.embeddedPPObj.closeFlow();
           // handle payment success here
           window.location.reload(true);
      };
      this.paymentCanceled = function () {
           this.embeddedPPObj.closeFlow();
           // handle payment cancellation here
           window.location.reload(true);
      };
   }
   var myEmbeddedPaymentFlow = new MyEmbeddedFlow(dgFlowMini);
```

`::PAYPAL_ADAPTIVE_GATEWAY.embedded_flow_url` is from activemerchant, you may use `'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay'` for sandbox or `'https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay'` for production.